# Assign boolean values to variables created from char list

Tags: haskell

I have two lists:
`"ab"` and `[False,True]`
Is it possible to create variables from first list and assign to them booleans from second list?
Something like this:

```
a = False
b = True
```

Comment: you mean creating tuples? using `zip`?

Comment: `zip "ab" [False, True]` outputs `[('a',False),('b',True)]`

Comment: You cannot dynamically create variable names from run-time data in Haskell (or if you can, it's almost certainly not the best way to do whatever it is you are trying to do in your program).

Comment: Through Template Haskell all things are possible.

Answer (score 1):

First the **technically-yes-but-please-don't-do-this**-it's-an-advanced-trick-that-should-only-be-used-if-you're-confident-this-is-really-what-you-want answer:

To generate variables guided by data you need Template Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module VariableGenerator where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import Control.Monad

generateVariables :: Lift t => [Char] -> [t] -> DecsQ
generateVariables is qs = concat <$> zipWithM (\i q -> [d| $(varP $ mkName [i]) = q |]) is qs
```

This can then be used in another module like

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import VariableGenerator

generateVariables "ab" [False, True]

main :: IO ()
main = do
   print a
   print b
```

---

### Proper answer

I think what you want is simply a map.

```
Prelude> import qualified Data.Map as Map
Prelude Map> let m = Map.fromList $ zip "ab" [False, True]
Prelude Map> m Map.! 'a'
False
Prelude Map> m Map.! 'b'
True
```

Comment: This only works for data that is known at compile time. And if the names are known at compile time, it would be simpler to just define the variables the ordinary way.